# Rails Sucker Punch - How to start jobs without visiting homepage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jobs, job-scheduling, sucker-punch

I'm trying to figure out how to have my background jobs in SuckerPunch start work without having to load the index page.

Right now, what I do is:

> $ rails server #starts the server at localhost:3000
>
> Then I go to my browser URL and enter localhost:3000

This triggers my SuckerPunch jobs, and they start running.

my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    # call job on application start
    TestEchoJob.new.async.perform("Download CMS Data")
    GetImages.new.async.perform
    DeleteImages.new.async.perform
    SendLead.new.async.perform

end
```

That's where I invoke the jobs.
I'm thinking maybe there is another place I can put them so I can achieve what I want.

Start the jobs on server start - not http request.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not be very specific, but I think all the info is in the sucker punch gem readme.  It will depend on your configuration, so please read that.

For example: (from the github repo)

**Active Job**

Sucker Punch has been added as an Active Job adapter in Rails 4.2. See the guide for configuration and implementation.

Add Sucker Punch to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sucker_punch'
```

And then configure the backend to use Sucker Punch:

```
# config/initializers/sucker_punch.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sucker_punch
end
```

Comment: It'd be good to extract the specific information you're referring to and include that in your answer.